# First time screen, Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

I want to restrict my user with terms and conditions popup after the first time of login and not to show the terms and condition once the user clicked agree to button. (And also to restrict the user not to access the other pages until he clicks the agree button). But when am trying, I cannot be able to get the exact scenario.

Comment: You'll want to use an `AuthGuard` to prevent the users to access the routes until after they accept your terms

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to add a flag on the user. Most of the time, this cannot be done in the front end of your application. The ideal solution for this is to add the flag on the user database, and the API should return it on each login action.

So you have to add column in your `user` table in your database, for example `hasAgreeTerms` and set it to true when the user has accepted the terms and conditions.

In your front part, you have to implements a `Guard` to restrict the access to others pages and to redirect the user to this specific page.

Hope it helps! :)